# Crystal Reports 13.07 for visual studio 2012 not rendering in Browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, crystal-reports

I am using a 64 bit machine(Windows 7),Visual studio 2012 ultimate(C#),asp.net
I installed crystal reports 13.07 from this link http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824
Tha above file installs the 64 bit runtime after the normal installation as it detects that I'm using a 64 bit machine.

Things go smooth until I run the application from the visual studio.
It displays a blank page in the Browser,instead of the report.
I am attaching the Aspx page, aspx.cs page, Crystal reports page ,Web config page and the browser page screenshots below.
How do I overcome this problem?

[image: Aspx page:]

[image: Aspx.Cs page:]

[image: Crystal Report Page]

[image: Web Config Page]

[image: This is what Displays in Browser]

Comment: Which runtime file did you install? You must install the exe for CR to get integrated with VS, the msi will not work. That is only for deployment on a client computer.

Comment: I installed the CRforVS_13_0_7.exe for visual studio . It detected that I have a 64 bit machine . So It Installed the 64 bit runtime after the normal installation.

Answer (score 0):

If you use IIS Express edition. then you have no support of crystal report.

hope you will find solution

Thanks
Tonmoy.